# Providing content from Ajax call to a separate method when onreadystatechange finds readState to be 4

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am writing a small JavaScript utilities library, a key requirement of which is a method that:

- Takes a URL and ID
- Uses these parameters to fetch content by Ajax (from the URL provided) and place it into a HTML element (specified by the ID).

The approach I am taking is:

1. Creating an object to namespace the library [Not immediately relevant, but it does explain the structure of the code below]
2. Writing generic methods that return ajax content based on a URL passed to it [*The requests are working fine, but providing the content to a separate function is where I'm having problems*]
3. Writing a generic method that will take the ajax method and place the value returned into a specified HTML element [I expect this will be quite straightforward, if I can fix point 2]

**My problem is that I have been unable to find a way to return content when onreadystatechange has identified the readyState to be 4. When this happens I need to be able to pass the value of this.returnText to a function that will place it into the HTML.**

The relevant code is below (included in full, but with the most relevant parts enclosed in a comment

```
// Init-time branching is used to detect objects and set functions accordingly.
var utilite = {
    addListener: null,
    removeListener: null,
    createAjaxObject: null,
    ajaxReadyStateHandler: function() {
          console.log('Ready state is: ' + this.readyState);
          if (this.readyState === 4) {
              // Check the status code:
              if ( (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) || (this.status === 304) ) {
                console.log('Status OK');
                if(this.status === 304){
                    console.log('Using cached version');
                }
                // Here's the problem: 
                // Despite 'testingAjax' being passed to the original calling function
                // I can't access it directly and am forced to hard-code it here.
                utilite.setElementContent({id: 'testingAjax', content: this.responseText});
              } else { // Status error!
                console.log('Status error: ' + this.statusText);
              }
          } // End of readyState IF.
      },
    doAjax: function(passedObject) {
    var ajax = utilite.createAjaxObject();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = utilite.ajaxReadyStateHandler;
    ajax.open(passedObject.requestType, passedObject.resource, true);
    ajax.send(null);
    },
    getElement: function (id) { // Retrieves element by passed id
        'use strict';
        if (typeof id == 'string') {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }
    },
    setElementContent: function(passedObject){
        'use strict';
        var theElement = utilite.getElement(passedObject.id);
        theElement.textContent = passedObject.content;
    }
}; // This is the end of utilite

// Event listener branches
if (typeof window.addEventListener === 'function') { // W3C and IE9
    utilite.addListener = function (obj, type, fn) {
        obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
    };
    utilite.removeListener = function (obj, type, fn) {
        obj.removeEventListener(type, fn, false);
    };
} else if (typeof document.attachEvent === 'function') { // IE
    utilite.addListener = function (obj, type, fn) {
        obj.attachEvent('on' + type, fn);
    };
    utilite.removeListener = function (obj, type, fn) {
        obj.detachEvent('on' + type, fn);
    };
} else { // DOM Level 0
    utilite.addListener = function (obj, type, fn) {
        obj['on' + type] = fn;
    };
    utilite.removeListener = function (obj, type, fn) {
        obj['on' + type] = null;
    };
}

// Ajax object creation branches
utilite.createAjaxObject = function() {
    var ajax = null;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // Older IE.
        ajax = new Ac
    var utilite = {
        addListener: null,
        removeListener: null,
        createAjaxObject: null,
        ajaxReadyStateHandler: function() {
              if (this.readyState === 4) {
                  if ( (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) || (this.status === 304) ) {
                    if(this.status === 304){
                        console.log('Using cached version');
                    }
                  /* -------------------------

                  It is the value of this.responseText here that I need to provide to a separate function

                  */ -------------------------
                  } else { // Status error!
                    console.log('Status error: ' + this.statusText);
                  }
              } // End of readyState IF.
          },
        doAjax: function(passedObject) {
        var ajax = utilite.createAjaxObject();
        ajax.onreadystatechange = utilite.ajaxReadyStateHandler;
        ajax.open(passedObject.requestType, passedObject.resource, true);
        ajax.send(null);
        },
        getElement: function (id) { // Retrieves element by passed id
            'use strict';
            if (typeof id == 'string') {
                return document.getElementById(id);
            }
        }
    }; // This is the end of utilite
    // Event listener branches
    if (typeof window.addEventListener === 'function') { // W3C and IE9
        utilite.addListener = function (obj, type, fn) {
            obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        };
        utilite.removeListener = function (obj, type, fn) {
            obj.removeEventListener(type, fn, false);
        };
    } else if (typeof document.attachEvent === 'function') { // IE
        utilite.addListener = function (obj, type, fn) {
            obj.attachEvent('on' + type, fn);
        };
        utilite.removeListener = function (obj, type, fn) {
            obj.detachEvent('on' + type, fn);
        };
    } else { // DOM Level 0
        utilite.addListener = function (obj, type, fn) {
            obj['on' + type] = fn;
        };
        utilite.removeListener = function (obj, type, fn) {
            obj['on' + type] = null;
        };
    }
    // Ajax object creation branches
    utilite.createAjaxObject = function() {
        var ajax = null;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // Older IE.
            ajax = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
        }
        return ajax;
    };
    init = function(){
        utilite.doAjax({requestType: 'GET', resource: 'test.txt'});
    };
    utilite.addListener(window, 'load', init);
tiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
    }
    return ajax;
};

init = function(){
    utilite.doAjax({requestType: 'GET', resource: 'test.txt', target: 'testingAjax'});
};

utilite.addListener(window, 'load', init);
```

Any and all help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would create two additional handlers, for example `AjaxSuccess` and `AjaxError`. You can then call `AjaxSuccess` from the `ajaxReadyStateHandler` with the `responseText` as a parameter. Also add the target DOM element as a parameter when binding the handler.

Why not check out the source code of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/) to check out how they handle these things? Or why not use these libraries, they are proven frameworks?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips. Unfortunately I can't use a library for this (believe me - I'm feeling the pain of knowing that I could achieve this with just 1 line of jQuery). I did try stepping through the jQuery source, but got lost quite quickly. I'll try the additional handlers but I'm still not sure how I'd return the value from AjaxSuccess to the original calling function. What I need is for the 'testingAjax' value not to be hard-coded into ajaxReadyStateHandler but to be obtained from the parameter passed to utilite.doAjax. Once again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

****UPDATED****

Do this:

Put this outside your ajax:

```
this.funcResp= function(resp){ console.log(resp) };
var thisObj=this;
```

Put this inside your ajax function:

```
thisObj.funcResp(responseText);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip but I couldn't get this to work - I suspect because 'this' refers to different contexts. Let me know if I'm missing something. Once again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for the responses. I have now managed to fix the problem using scope. Here's how:

1. Added a property to the namespaced object called elementToUpdate.
2. Had the doAjax() function change the value of elementToUpdate.
3. Referenced elementToUpdate from ajaxReadyStateHandler().

This works nicely but does have a bit of a problem when doAjax() is called repeatedly. I suspect this is because elementToUpdate is being referenced/updated repeatedly. I'll fix this another time.

Many thanks again. Code shown below. 
G

```
// Init-time branching is used to detect objects and set functions accordingly.

    var utilite = { 
    addListener: null,
    removeListener: null,
    createAjaxObject: null,
    elementToUpdate: null,
    ajaxReadyStateHandler: function() {
          console.log('Ready state is: ' + this.readyState);
          if (this.readyState === 4) {
              // Check the status code:
              if ( (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) || (this.status === 304) ) {
                console.log('Status OK');
                if(this.status === 304){
                    console.log('Using cached version');
                }
                // Note: elementToUpdate is accessible here because of the way scope works
                utilite.setElementContent({id: elementToUpdate, content: this.responseText});
              } else { // Status error!
                console.log('Status error: ' + this.statusText);
              }
          } // End of readyState IF.
      },
    doAjax: function(passedObject) {
    elementToUpdate = passedObject.target;
    var ajax = utilite.createAjaxObject();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = utilite.ajaxReadyStateHandler;
    ajax.open(passedObject.requestType, passedObject.resource, true);
    ajax.send(null);
    },
    getElement: function (id) { // Retrieves element by passed id
        'use strict';
        if (typeof id == 'string') {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }
    },
    setElementContent: function(passedObject){
        'use strict';
        var theElement = utilite.getElement(passedObject.id);
        if(typeof theElement.innerText !== 'undefined') { theElement.innerText = passedObject.content; }
        if(typeof theElement.textContent !== 'undefined') { theElement.textContent = passedObject.content; }
    }
}; // This is the end of utilite

// Event listener branches
if (typeof window.addEventListener === 'function') { // W3C and IE9
    utilite.addListener = function (obj, type, fn) {
        obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
    };
    utilite.removeListener = function (obj, type, fn) {
        obj.removeEventListener(type, fn, false);
    };
} else if (typeof document.attachEvent === 'function') { // IE
    utilite.addListener = function (obj, type, fn) {
        obj.attachEvent('on' + type, fn);
    };
    utilite.removeListener = function (obj, type, fn) {
        obj.detachEvent('on' + type, fn);
    };
} else { // DOM Level 0
    utilite.addListener = function (obj, type, fn) {
        obj['on' + type] = fn;
    };
    utilite.removeListener = function (obj, type, fn) {
        obj['on' + type] = null;
    };
}

// Ajax object creation branches
utilite.createAjaxObject = function() {
    var ajax = null;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // Older IE.
        ajax = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
    }
    return ajax;
};

init = function(){
    utilite.doAjax({requestType: 'GET', resource: 'test.txt', target: 'funky'});
};

utilite.addListener(window, 'load', init);
```